# Problem with Repeated Blender Crashes

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, error

I'm new. :) I've been modeling a living room in Blender 4.0 and it keeps crashing a lot.  At first, it worked great. Then it started slowing down and freezing up. Now I barely have to click on the model a few times and Blender will freeze up. The screen will turn gray and say "not responding", and my mouse will spin. Often I have to restart my whole computer because the screen is frozen or the mouse won't move.

I tried opening the file in Blender 3.6 and it has the same problem. It slows down all my applications and takes forever to load them. I'm still able to use Grease Pencil and do small scale things in the 3d workspace.

I've had Blender on my computer for a year and a half. It's always worked fine.  My computer is a two year old laptop HP. My system is Windows 11 and my CPU processor is AMD Ryzen 5 5500U with Radeon Graphics. My GPU is AMD Radeon (TM) Graphics. I have lots of memory and 11 GB of RAM space. What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome. This looks like a hardware limitation

Comment: So it's not because the file is so large? I've imported large models before and it wasn't a problem.

Comment: Yes, the more objects you have, the harder for your hardware to manage

Comment: You wrote a lot of text but all we know at the end is that you have 11GB of ram and a specific file or two that slow down or crash. We can't help much from this little information. You could try to troubleshoot the crash using [Crashes — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/crash.html). How many triangles do you have in that scene before crashing? What is your system, cpu and gpu models? Please [edit] your question to have the right informations we need.

Comment: Note that, while we can help if the crashes come from a misusage of Blender, we can't do anything if it's a bug from Blender or a third-party addon, those would need to be reported on the respective bug trackers.

Comment: I used planes for building the set, if that's what you mean. Sorry, I'm still relatively new to Blender's 3d space. I apologize for not wording my question correctly.

Comment: You don't have a dedicated GPU?  That can be problematic. Enable "statistics" in the [overlays popover](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html#bpy-types-view3doverlay), deselect everything and tell us what is the amount of triangles shown in the statistics in the top left corner of the viewport.

Comment: I know this may be tedious, but you could try step-by step debugging your scene. In a fresh file, append objects, most suspicious first, from the bad one.

Comment: I enabled Statistics and it shows I have 2 / 814,057 triangles.

Comment: I can tell at least that [your CPU is recent enough for Blender](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/). Have you followed the Crash troubleshooting link I sent earlier? The crash logs you can get from there could tell what's going on.

Comment: 800k triangles should be fine with 11GB of ram, if your ram isn't bloated by other softwares already.

Comment: I'm working on the Crash troubleshooting. I will post when I have more info. I don't have many applications installed on my computer. My Task Manager says that Blender takes up 29.2 MB when it's closed and 410.1 MB when it's opened. My System Information app says that I have 12 GB of installed Physical Memory (RAM), 11 GB total Physical Memory, and 1.10 GB available Physical Memory.

Comment: I have an antivirus software on my laptop that keeps giving me notifications that my storage is below 17%. I think my problem is that I have too many junk files. How would I go about deleting them safely without erasing my personal files?